# How do you safely load external JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript

Is there a safe way to load external JavaScript file? In a situation when the external or internal host/server/URL is NOT reachable?

I want to know how can I make sure the page is not slowing down - it can look bad or miss functionality (due to the script not loading correctly).

Is "async=true" is all you need to do?

Thanks

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here, I suggest you make it clearer what question it is you'd like help with.

Comment: I updated the questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) and/or [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) attributes.

- `async`, if the attribute is present, then the classic script will be fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated as soon as it is available.
- `defer` will indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed

```html
<script 
    type="application/javascript" 
    src="https://example.com/something.min.js" 
    async 
    defer>
</script>
```